# AttributeError with non-model Field serialization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And I need to serialize creation of User and Model. Idea is to ask User company name while doing registration, so I have:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'company_name', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data['username']
        email = validated_data['email']
        password = validated_data['password']
        company_name = validated_data['company_name']
        user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email, password=password)
        Company.objects.create(user=user, name=company_name)
        return user
```

And I get error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
>   `company_name` on serializer `CreateUserSerializer`. The serializer
>   field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on
>   the `User` instance. Original exception text was: 'User' object has no
>   attribute 'company_name'.

Anyway objects Company and User are created as I can see it in my admin panel.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`source`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) field's argument in this case:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, source='company.name')
```

Comment: now get KeyError at /api/customers/create_user
'company_name'

Comment: @D.Make Try `company_name = validated_data['company']['name']` instead of `company_name = validated_data['company_name']`.

Comment: you made it clear how it works! Thanks again. And I found a mistake in my code - User.object.create is the wrong way to create users. I supposed to use User.object.create_user. Is it correct?

Comment: @D.Make you are right. You should use `create_user` it's doing pasword hashing automatically and normalizing email and username fields.